# Spring Data Jpa sorting and pagination of child entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Parent and Child entity with 1-m relation which is undirectional from Parent to Child. And I want to get all children knowing the parent id with sorting and pagination. 
I've tried the following using Spring Data:
- create a query on entities using @Query but the sorting is only available for Parent entity
- tried a native query but this doesn't support pagination and sorting 
- tried to use PagingAndSortingRepository but it has just a findAll() which will bring all Parent records and not just one

Do you have any more ideas for doing this with Spring Data or should I try something else like Criteria from Hibernate?

Here is what I've tried(Leg is parent entity and Cashflows is child entity):

```
@Repository
public interface CashflowRepository extends JpaRepository<Cashflow, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT cf FROM Leg leg JOIN leg.cashflows cf WHERE 
       leg.id=:legId",
       countQuery = "SELECT count(cf) FROM Leg leg JOIN leg.cashflows cf 
       WHERE leg.id=:legId")
Page<Cashflow> findByLeg(@Param("legId") Long legId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And I call the repository like this:

```
cashflowRepository.findByLeg(1234, new PageRequest(1, 20, new Sort(
            new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "paymentDate"))));
```

The problem is that the sorting attribute `"paymentDate"` is applied to parent entity(`Leg`) and not to the child(`Cashflows`).

```
See the exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: paymentDate of: com.db.treasury.tpmt.model.Leg [SELECT cf FROM com.db.treasury.tpmt.model.Leg leg JOIN leg.cashflows cf WHERE leg.id=:legId order by leg.paymentDate desc]
```

Comment: If you want to get a page of child entities, then create a query returning child entities. Not a query returning the parent entity. Something like `select c from Parent p join p.children c where ...`.

Comment: Yes I've tried like this but the Sort object of Pageable is applied to the Parent and I need for Child

Comment: Why don't you post what you tried?

Comment: @Query(value = "SELECT cf FROM leg.cashflows cf JOIN Leg leg WHERE leg.id=:legId ",
       countQuery = "SELECT count(cf) FROM Leg leg JOIN leg.cashflows cf WHERE leg.id=:legId")
Page<Cashflow> findByLeg(@Param("legId") Long legId, Pageable pageable);   

Leg is the parent entity and Cashflows is the child, but the Pageable object is applied to the parent and not to the child.

Comment: This is not a valid JPQL query. Post all the relevant code in the question, properly formatted.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT c FROM Cashflow c WHERE c.leg = :legId` on the `CashflowRepository`?

Comment: Because there is a unidirectional relationship between Leg and Cashflow I can't navigate from Cashflow to Leg

Comment: @JBNizet I've updated the question with formatted code

Comment: In your Sort, replace "paymentDate" by "cf.paymentDate"

Comment: @JBNizet If I do like that it will be like leg.cf.paymentDate

Comment: No, it won't be like that.

Comment: @JBNizet I've tried like that and that was outputed in the exception

Comment: Then you probably have an old version of Spring data jpa. I tested your use-cae, with that solution, using version 2.0.0, and it works fine. Note that is you always want to sort by paymentDate, you can hardcode that in the query, and avoid passing a Sort in the page request.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, I have a version older than 2.0.0, I'll come back with an answer after I update the version..and the sort attribute is not static as it's selectable from ui

Comment: @JBNizet I've tried to update Spring Data to 2.0.0 version but it seems that it uses java 8 and my project is on java 7..